# Ember 1.13 upgradation

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-1

I'm upgrading the code from Ember 1.0.4 to Ember 1.13. When I'm execute the below code using ember 1.13 I'm getting the error

```
title: Ember.computed('content.title', 'managedObject.isHome', 'managedObject.finalManagedObject', {
                set: function(name, value) {
                    this.set('content.title', value);
                },
                if (this.get('content.title') !== undefined) {
                    return title;
                }
                if (this.get('managedObject') == Core.rootNode) {
                    return "Home";
                }
                get: function() {
                  return this.get('managedObject.label') || this.get('managedObject.finalManagedObject.displayName');
                }
            }),
```

I'm getting the below error while execute the code.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this
```

Comment: at which line number you are getting error ?

Comment: `if` and `return` inside javascript object? This is something new!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by using the below code:

```
title: Ember.computed('content.title', 'managedObject', 'managedObject.label', 'managedObject.finalManagedObject.displayName', {
                set: function(titleKey, newTitle) {
                    this.set('content.title', newTitle);
                    if (newTitle !== undefined) {
                        return newTitle;
                    } else if (this.get('managedObject') === Core.rootNode) {
                        return 'Home';
                    }
                    return this.get('managedObject.label') || this.get('managedObject.finalManagedObject.displayName');
                },      
                get: function() {
                    var title = this.get('content.title');
                    if (title !== undefined) {
                        return title;
                    } else if (this.get('managedObject') === Core.rootNode) {
                        return 'Home';
                    }
                    return this.get('managedObject.label') || this.get('managedObject.finalManagedObject.displayName');
                }
            }),
```

Thanks for your suggestions Rinold Simon and jelhan.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an object to define a computed property. That object must have a `get` and may have a `set` function. Both are present. But you have six additional that aren't valid syntax in object definition. You are trying to construct an object like this:

```
{
  set: function(name, value) {
    this.set('content.title', value);
  },
  if (this.get('content.title') !== undefined) {
     return title;
  }
  if (this.get('managedObject') == RSuite.rootNode) {
    return "Home";
  }
  get: function() {
    return this.get('managedObject.label') || this.get('managedObject.finalManagedObject.displayName');
  }
}
```

The valid part of that object is:

```
{
  set: function(name, value) {
    this.set('content.title', value);
  },
  get: function() {
    return this.get('managedObject.label') || this.get('managedObject.finalManagedObject.displayName');
  }
}
```

Depending on your babel configuration you might be able to simplify it to:

```
{
  set(name, value) {
    this.set('content.title', value);
  },
  get() {
    return this.get('managedObject.label') || this.get('managedObject.finalManagedObject.displayName');
  }
}
```

I hope it's clear now. This has nothing to do with upgrade from Ember 1.0.4 to Ember 1.13 in particular. Please have in mind that Ember 1.13 is very old. 2.0 was released more than three years ago. So I would strongly recommend to continue migration until you reach at least to 2.18.

Comment: I think this is the exact one which even I suggested. But the issue is with why it throws `Unexpected token this`. Removing the `if` statements will possibly solve the issue

Answer (score -2):

I think the `this` reference is lost. Try replacing your code with the below one,

```
title: Ember.computed('content.title', 'managedObject.isHome', 'managedObject.finalManagedObject', {
  set(name, value) {
    this.set('content.title', value);
  },
  get() {
    return this.get('managedObject.label') || this.get('managedObject.finalManagedObject.displayName');
  }      
  if (this.get('content.title') !== undefined) {
    return title;
  }
  if (this.get('managedObject') == RSuite.rootNode) {
    return "Home";
  }
}),
```

Comment: Hi @rinold, I'm getting same issue on this line `if (this.get('content.title') !== undefined)`

Comment: at which line are you getting error in your example code ?

Comment: On the same line of the code which I mentioned in comment before.

Comment: try removing `,` which is above if statement

Comment: Already I have tried before removing `,`. Still getting same issues